# Applescript - Escaping Quotes When Setting Excel Formula

Tags: excel, applescript

I've searched extensively for the answer to my question and I'm at an impasse.

I'm trying to pass a formula to excel with applescript. The problem is the quotes around the spaces that I want to place between fields. I've used "\" to escape the quotes but it throws an error. To make it more complicated the row number is a variable "i". Here is the formula in excel format:

```
=CONCATENATE(A2," ",B2," ",C2," ",D2)
```

Here is the formula in applescript-ese (works but does not produce spaces in data):

```
set rowCount to (((count of rows of used range of active sheet)) + 1)
repeat with i from rowCount to 2 by -1
set formula of row i of column 15 to "=CONCATENATE(A" & i & "," & ",B" & i & "," & ",C" & i & "," & ",D" & i & ")"
```

Here is the formula with escaped quotes to add the spaces (gives error):

```
set formula of row i of column 15 to"=CONCATENATE(A" & i & ","\" \" & ",B" & i & ","\" \" & ",C" & i & ","\" \" & ",D" & i & ")"
```

I get a sytax error on the first slash; *Expected end of line etc. but found unknown token.*  I have a feeling I'm either missing a few sets of double quotes or I'm making this way more complicated than it needs to be. Any ideas? Should I be going about this differently?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

Taking another look at it I think you have too many quotes when you use the \ character to escape the double quote.  Instead of `","\" \" & ",B"` try `",\" \",B"` so your line would look like this:

```
set formula of row i of column 15 to "=CONCATENATE(A" & i & ",\" \",B" & i & ",\" \",C" & i & ",\" \",D" & i & ")"
```

---

In excel VBA you can double quote a double quote to get it to show up in a string like this:

```
"=CONCATENATE(A" & i & "," & """ """ & ",B" & i & "," & """ """ & ",C" & i & "," & """ """ & ",D" & i & ")"
```

---

Or you can try using ascii character for space which is `Chr(32)`

Comment: I really liked the idea of using ascii because it makes for cleaner code but it breaks.  I might not be coding it correctly.
error "Microsoft Excel got an error: Can’t continue Chr." number -1708
set formula of row i of column 14 to "=CONCATENATE(A" & i & "," & Chr(32) & ",B" & i & "," & Chr(32) & ",C" & i & "," & Chr(32) & ",D" & i & ")"



The quoted version also sends back a syntax error Expected end of line etc. but found """.

Thanks for the help, by the way.

Comment: See my edit, I think you had an extra double quote before each back slash.

Comment: You are absolutely right.  You solved it. I had gone crazy with the quotes.  It can get complicated to wrap my head around alternating between text and code.  And, for the record, I'm pretty new to Applescript, so I REALLY appreciate the help.  Your ascii solution reminded me of all the VBscript I used to write years ago.

Thanks again!